# Is it natural and correct to to say "something is worth its money" when I want to say that I got my money worth from that?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is it natural and correct to to say *something is worth its money* when I want to say that I got my money worth from that? For example:

> The tablet works really good. It's **worth its money**.

If it doesn't sound good, how would you communicate the message?

Comment: I would say 'worth the money'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both literally and idiomatically, it would be incorrect to say that the tablet 'possesses' the money it costs to buy it.

It would be more appropriate to say

> It's worth its price

Or, as Kate says in their comment:

> It's worth the money

In the second phrase what's really being said is

> It's worth the money [it costs to buy it]

but we can drop the latter part.